# How to load grouped annotation point from SQLite

Tags: ios, sqlite, mapkit

I have a database that contains 16000 annotations. When the user is zooming out, there are too many points loaded and points overlap. I found a filter with code but i want to load some point only from SQL, not to load all and filter it after. I don't know if there is a stored procedure in iOS or other solution.

This is my code

```
iphoneScaleFactorLatitude = 3.3;
    float iphoneScaleFactorLongitude = 6.38;
    float latDelta  = self.mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta/iphoneScaleFactorLatitude;
    float longDelta = self.mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta/iphoneScaleFactorLongitude;

    NSMutableArray *shopsToShow = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
        for (int i=0; i<[placesToFilter count]; i++) {
            MKPointAnnotation *checkingLocation   = [placesToFilter objectAtIndex:i];
            CLLocationDegrees latitude  = [checkingLocation coordinate].latitude;
            CLLocationDegrees longitude = [checkingLocation coordinate].longitude;

            bool found=FALSE;

            for (MKPointAnnotation *tempPlacemark in shopsToShow) {
                if(fabs([tempPlacemark coordinate].latitude-latitude) < latDelta &&
                   fabs([tempPlacemark coordinate].longitude-longitude) <longDelta ){
                    [self.mapView removeAnnotation:checkingLocation];
                    found = TRUE;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!found){
                [shopsToShow addObject:checkingLocation];
                [self.mapView addAnnotation:checkingLocation];
            }
        }
```

But they load too many point and my problem is that I don't want to load all the points because each chagement I have to use the algorithm to the sorting.

Comment: i don't see how that would be possible as it seems to me that you have to observe all of your data to know how to filter them.

Comment: There is no possibility to filter it in sqlite before load?

Comment: probably depends on your filtering algorithm. can you post it ?